# Expand JButton in GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

How to expand `JButton` in `GridBagLayout`?

I tried setting the weights of the `GridBagConstraints` to non-zero values:

```
gbc.weightx = gbc.weighty = 1.0;
```

But it's only expanding width of the buttons, I want buttons to expand vertically too.

[image]

Here is the code in which I add buttons in grid:

```
private void initGui(){
    setTitle("Calculator");
    setSize(400,500);
    var grid = new GridBagLayout();
    setLayout(grid);
    GridBagConstraints gridCon = new GridBagConstraints();
    gridCon.weightx = gridCon.weighty = 1.0;

    gridCon.gridy = 0;
    gridCon.gridx = 0;
    gridCon.gridwidth = 4;
    gridCon.fill = gridCon.HORIZONTAL;
    add(text,gridCon);

    gridCon.gridwidth = 1 ;

    String names[] = {"+","-","/","*","="};
    for(int i = 0;i < 5; i++){
        opeButtons[i] = new JButton(names[i]);
    }

    gridCon.gridx = 3;
    for( int y = 1; y < 6; y++ ){
        gridCon.gridy = y;
        add(opeButtons[y-1],gridCon);
    }

    for(int y = 2, i = 1; y < 5; y++ ){
        for(int x = 0 ; x < 3; x++,i++) {
            gridCon.gridx = x;
            gridCon.gridy = y;
            numButtons[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
            add(numButtons[i],gridCon);
        }
    }

    gridCon.gridx = 0;
    gridCon.gridy = 1;
    add(lb,gridCon);
    gridCon.gridx = 1;
    add(rb,gridCon);
    gridCon.gridx = 2;
    add(cb,gridCon);

    numButtons[0] = new JButton("0");
    gridCon.gridx = 0;
    gridCon.gridy = 5;
    gridCon.gridwidth = 2;
    add(numButtons[0],gridCon);

    gridCon.gridwidth = 1;
    gridCon.gridx = 2;
    add(decb,gridCon);
}
```

Comment: This: `gridCon.fill = gridCon.HORIZONTAL;` should be `gridCon.fill = gridCon.BOTH;` for the JButton. Makes sense when you think about it, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
gridCon.fill = gridCon.HORIZONTAL;
```

with

```
gridCon.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

Comment: Looks vaguely familiar. ;)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels As a proper (community wiki) answer. Thanks for removing the the nasty static referenced by expression.